# Delete part of a row and shift dataframe up in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames I am attempting to join into one.

They both have identical layouts like this:

```
Dataframe A 
Time   Reading 1   R2   R3
1:20       1       3    4
1:21       5       4    2
1:22       6       2    1
1:23       7       8    9

Dataframe B
Time    Sensor1   S2   S3
1:20       1       5    2
1:22       3       8    4
1:23       2       4    7
1:24       5       6    8
```

And join them like so:

```
Dataframe C
Time   Reading 1   R2   R3   Time2   Sensor1   S2   S3
1:20       1       3    4    1:20       1       5    2
1:21       5       4    2    1:22       3       8    4
1:22       6       2    1    1:23       2       4    7
1:23       7       8    9    1:24       5       6    8
```

However, you can see the discrepancy in timings between the first and the second, as 1:21 is missing. What I am trying to do is delete the columns associated with reading for that row (but keep the sensor ones), and shift the remaining columns up one.

Like so:

```
Dataframe C
Time   Reading 1   R2   R3   Time2   Sensor1   S2   S3
1:20       1       3    4    1:20       1       5    2
1:22       6       2    1    1:22       3       8    4
1:23       7       8    9    1:23       2       4    7
                             1:24       5       6    8
```

I have already joined them into Dataframe C. I know I can shift the columns up by using df.x.shift(-1), but what would be a good way of approaching the problem in terms of comparing each row for the time columns, and deleting the columns? It is tedious as this is a large dataset. Any help is appreciated

Comment: if you have still access to both A and B dataframes, the easiest would be to use `merge` instead of `join` on Time and Time2 to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you one consolidated view -

```
>>> A.merge(B, on='Time', how='right')
   Time  Reading  1   R2   R3  Sensor1  S2  S3
0  1:20         1.0  3.0  4.0        1   5   2
1  1:22         6.0  2.0  1.0        3   8   4
2  1:23         7.0  8.0  9.0        2   4   7
3  1:24         NaN  NaN  NaN        5   6   8
```